# NSLog save to array

Tags: ios, swift

I want to create `My Log` function that returns same information like NSlog, but i want to save this logs to array. I don't understand how to generate time in this format and current line where it calls(`NSLog` seems show incorrect lines):

```
2016-03-09 10:20:09.520 My project[1031:15198]
```